# How to run an Event Handler event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am new to discord bot development and I am unable to run my events. I applied the same logic as in Commands Handler, but apparently it didn't work. I tried to force the execution of the ready event with `const event = client.events.get("ready"); event.run(client);` however it returns undefined as the value of `event`.
I apologize if it is 'obvious', but I really haven't found anything that could help me resolve it.

index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

for (const file2 of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file2}`);
    client.events.set(event.name, event);
}

const event = client.events.get("ready");
event.run(client);

client.login();
```

ready.js

```
module.exports = {
    event: "ready",
    once: true,

    run(client) {
        console.log('Ready!');
        client.user.setActivity('A!help  /  A!info', { type: 'STREAMING', url: 'https://www.twitch.tv/' });
    }
};
```

files:

```
-index.js
-events
     -ready.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer:**

You are calling the wrong object key for event. Try:

```
client.events.set(event.event, event);
```

**Edit:**

You need to wait for the client to be ready. Then when you login, you need to provide your bot token:

index.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

for (const file2 of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file2}`);
    client.events.set(event.event, event);
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    const event = client.events.get("ready");
    event.run(client);
});

client.login(process.env.token);
```

.env:

```
token="YOUR BOT TOKEN"
```

Comment: This worked, i managed to run ready.js, but the console returned another error now `Cannot read property 'setActivity' of null`. I think I did something wrong with the client. Do you imagine what it can be?

Answer (score 1):

The module you are exporting in `ready.js` doesn't have the property `name` only `event`, which is supposed to be the name from the event I assume.

You have 2 solutions:

1. Change the property `event` to `name`
2. Replace the trigger of the event from `name` to `event`

Solution Number 1:

```
// In your ready.js
name: "ready",
```

Solution 2:

```
client.events.set(event.event, event);
```

> the console returned another error now `Cannot read property 'setActivity' of null`

You are triggering the event before your bot is online. So you need to wait until the client got the event `ready` triggered.

This can be done by writing in your index.js

```
const event = client.events.get("ready");
client.on("ready", () => event.run(client));
```